# Using UIDatePicker with UITextField without textfield edit

Tags: ios, swift

Right now I have a view controller with a text field.

When I click into the text field, a UIDatePicker is displayed instead of the normal keyboard.

Selecting a date/time in the UIDataPicker, updates the text field.

This is my code:

```
@IBAction func fieldValueEditingDidBegin(sender: UITextField) {
    if self.dateTimeEdit {
      let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
      datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
      sender.inputView = datePickerView
      datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }
  }


  func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

    fieldValueTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    doneBarButtonItem.enabled = true
  }
```

I want to prevent the user from inputting other text in the UITextField (e.g. using external keyboard or pasting a string)

Is it possible to force the use of the UIDataPicker only and prevent typing in the UITextField?

Comment: Why don't you use a `UILabel` instead of a textfield?

Comment: because  UILabel don't have inputView

Comment: If you're going to limit all populating of the input to a date picker, then you shouldn't need the functionality of inputting text. You can add a tap gesture to a label and have the date picker choice populate the label's text.

Answer (score 2):

One simple workaround:
You can use, the [shouldChangeCharactersInRange](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:) UITextfieldDelegate method.

Since this method is called only when the user enter text (not when you set it programmatically) you can just return false.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

I have finally solved my problem using a label and displaying the datatimepicker in the tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath event.

In the viewDidLoad

```
popDatePickerFechaInicio = PopDatePicker(forLabelField: fechaInicioLabel)
```

and in the tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

```
let initDate = self.fechaInicioLabel.text?.ToDateFromDateTimeShort() ?? NSDate()
let dataChangedCallback : PopDatePicker.PopDatePickerCallback = { (newDate : NSDate, forLabelField : UILabel) -> () in
     forLabelField.text = (newDate.ToDateTimeShortString() ?? "?") as String
        }
popDatePickerFechaInicio!.pick(self, initDate: initDate, dataChanged: dataChangedCallback)
```